# Extract variables from char vectors

Tags: r, statistics, glm

I want to create a logistic model from a data frame.

```
#''data.frame':   6532 obs. of  12 variables:
#$ NewsDesk      : chr  "Business" "Culture" "Business" "Business" ...
#$ SectionName   : chr  "Crosswords/Games" "Arts" "Business Day" "Business Day" ...
#$ SubsectionName: chr  "" "" "Dealbook" "Dealbook" ...
#$ Headline      : chr  "More School Daze" "New 96-Page Murakami Work Coming in December" "Public Pension Funds Stay Mum on Corporate Expats" "Boot Camp for Bankers" ...
#$ Snippet       : chr  "A puzzle from Ethan Cooper that reminds me that a bill is due." "The Strange Library will arrive just three and a half months after Mr. Murakamis latest novel, Colorless Tsukuru Tazaki and His"| __truncated__ "Public pension funds have major stakes in American companies moving overseas to cut their tax bills. But they are saying little"| __truncated__ "As they struggle to find new business to bolster sluggish earnings, banks consider the nations 25 million veterans and service "| __truncated__ ...
#$ Abstract      : chr  "A puzzle from Ethan Cooper that reminds me that a bill is due." "The Strange Library will arrive just three and a half months after Mr. Murakamis latest novel, Colorless Tsukuru Tazaki and His"| __truncated__ "Public pension funds have major stakes in American companies moving overseas to cut their tax bills. But they are saying little"| __truncated__ "As they struggle to find new business to bolster sluggish earnings, banks consider the nations 25 million veterans and service "| __truncated__ ...
#$ WordCount     : int  508 285 1211 1405 181 245 258 893 1077 188 ...
#$ PubDate       : POSIXlt, format: "2014-09-01 22:00:09" "2014-09-01 21:14:07" ...
#$ Popular       : int  1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 ...
```

There are 11 categories in `NewsDesk`.

```
       # Business  Culture  Foreign Magazine    Metro National     OpEd  Science   Sports 
# 1846     1548      676      375       31      198        4      521      194        2 
#Styles   Travel   TStyle 
# 297      116      724
```

However, I just need `OpEd, Business, Science, Culture, TStyle` to create the model according to significance. I have no idea how I should extract these factors from `NewsDesk`? Any ideas on that?

Comment: @Alex A:Maybe I just asked my question in a vague way. I already made the corpus from Headline and Abstract, extract the weekday and hour from PubDate. I want to make a glm model with all independent variables to predict Popular of a blog. But I guess there is over-fitting or multicolinearity issues due to too many coefficients.So I want extract some levels from NewsDesk and SectionName.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand now. What you'll need to do is either subset your data frame to remove those observations or keep the observations but recode the unwanted values to something else.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do as following.

```
set.seed(1237)
NewDesk <- sample(c("OpEd", "Business", "Science", "Culture", "TStyle", "Foreign",
         "Magazine", "Metro", "Sports", "Styles", "Travel"), 100, replace = T)
df <- data.frame(Popular = sample(0:1, 100, replace = T), NewDesk = NewDesk)
filter <- c("OpEd", "Business", "Science", "Culture", "TStyle")

head(df[df$NewDesk %in% filter, ])

#   Popular  NewDesk
#1        0  Culture
#3        0     OpEd
#4        0 Business
#5        1  Science
#8        1   TStyle
#11       1 Business
```